# How does Intel processor access Branch Trace Store buffer?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, kernel, intel

The intel processor features Branch Trace Store(BTS), recording the branches and store them in the buffer specified by the user/program. In fact I am wondering whether the processor access the BTS buffer through MMU unit(page table) or it just directly physically access the BTS buffer?

Answer (score 4):

From [Intel Manual Volume 3, Chapter 17.4.9 (BTS and DS Save Area)](http://www.intel.it/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-system-programming-manual-325384.pdf) an image for the 32 bit version of the *Debug Store* area

[image]

> **BTS buffer base** — Linear address of the first byte of the BTS buffer. This address should point to a natural doubleword boundary.

and for the *IA32_DS_AREA* MSR

> Write the **base linear address** of the DS buffer management area into the IA32_DS_AREA MSR.

---

In general every address you set to the processor is a linear address so that is it independent of the segments set and so that paging take place only if activated.
Of course this is true only where it doesn't create recursive dependency, like with the *CR3* register.

To directly answer your question: *If paging is activated, the address given is translated otherwise it is used as is*.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by `if paging is activated` or is that true on normal PC installed with modern Linux operating system, the paging is activated?

Comment: @user2579274 yes sorry, all modern OSes use paging, so it's true that Linux use it too. It is just that paging it a feature that must be explicitly activated.